# Django: How to edit value and store back in database

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm working on an attendance register. So I've got an HTMl checkbox form where user can tick if person is here. If they are then the views will pull out the number of lessons person has in database and subtract 1 from the value. How can I achieve this? This is done using Django.

views.py:

```
def present(request):
    students = Student.objects.filter(squad='LearnToSwim1')
    completed = request.GET.get('pre')
    for stu in students:
        if request.POST.get('completed', '') == 'on':
            print("Present!")
        #I don't know what to do here to extract the lessons_left and subtract 1 from it.
        else:
            print("Not present")
```

models.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    squad = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=SQUAD, default='INSERT_SQUAD')
    lessons_left=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_name
```

presentform.html:

```
<form action="/present/" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %} 
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="completed" name="completed" />  
            <label for="completed">Present</label>
        </p>
            <input class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type='submit'/> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you simply use `save()` or `update()` method.

```
stu.lessons_left -= 1
stu.save()
```

or use `update` that you don't have to use for loop.

```
Student.objects.filter(squad='LearnToSwim1').update(lessons_left-=1)
```

If I missed something, tell me.

### UPDATE

As @Cesar said, I updated to use `F` expression.

```
from django.db.models import F
Student.objects.filter(squad='LearnToSwim1').update(lessons_left=F(lessens_left)+1)
```

And as @Gospodinov said, if there's a possibility of simultaneity, you can use transaction. (But I guess `update()` method is enough for control it.)

Comment: Python throws syntax error at `lessons_left -= 1`  at the `-=` which is very strange but that logic would work thank you.

Comment: You should use F expressions for doing arithmetic operations in the database, your solution might fail in a concurrent scenario.

Comment: I guess you cannot use it in update() method. Just use `update(lesson_left='your_number')` instead

Comment: @CesarCanassa works! Thank you! But say I have multiple present buttons. How would I be able to do subtract for each button?

Comment: As @CesarCanassa said, it's not a good idea to -= directly on the instance's value.  It might clash and it will be decreased only once if you have multiple requests which are modifing the lessons_left.